# Why am I getting a kernel crash on Chop?

Tags: bugs, kernel, crash, predictive-interface

**`Solve` bug (see answer) introduced in 9.0 and persisting through 11.0.1 or later**

---

First post, hopefully I figure out the formatting easily.  Please forgive me if this posts ugly.

I am having a (repeatable) problem where when I run my code everything works fast and the output is displayed but the program has some error in which it erases the kernel (maybe that's not the correct term). Basically all my variables reset and *Mathematica* goes back to being as if I just opened the software.

For context, this is the output of a secular variation model

```
(0.0057300369 - 0.0071475265 I) E^((-8.2717832*10^-25 +  6.6290151*10^-9 I) t) -
(0.0000981431 +  0.0001437239 I) E^((-3.7695835*10^-29 +  1.4229429*10^-9 I) t) +
(0.000072401667 -   0.000092434689 I) E^((0. +   2.6555734*10^-8 I) t) +
(0.000092742725 -   0.000015933052 I) E^((4.0245734*10^-26 + 3.1934271*10^-10 I) t)
```

Those real pieces in the exponential are really zero except for some numerical error.  I want to `// Chop` it.  When I do however, my machine makes a "dong" sound (standard Mac error sound) and *Mathematica* or the kernel resets.

I would guess it is repeatable for anyone else to try as well.  I completely quit *Mathematica*. Reopen then copy paste the block above into a new window.  A chop at the end of it has the same result.

It spits out the right answer, but this is just a step in a loop, so I need all my variables and such to stay defined.

Any reason someone can see that this is happening?

#### Edit

My guess is *Mathematica* just needs a real component in the exponential. Don't know why, though.

Take that bit above and use `// ComplexExpand //Chop` gives it in an equivalent form in sines and cosines.

Comment: I can confirm the same in Win8.1 with MMA10.

Comment: I don't see this  on MMA10, Win7-64.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on OS X 10.9.4, M 10.0.0.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on Ubuntu Linux 12.04, M 10.0.0

Comment: I am in version 9.0.1.0 for the record with OSX 10.9.2

Comment: I don't see this in 9.0.1 Win7-64 either

Comment: No problem with 9.0.1 and 10.0.0 on Win8.1 x64.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The crash may be avoided by [turning off](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/75284/121) the Suggestions Bar.

The reason is that one of the computations attempted by the predictive interface in the background, namely

```
 Solve[(0.000092742725 - 0.000015933052*I)*
   E^((0. + 3.1934271000000003*^-10*I)*t) - (0.0000981431 + 
       0.0001437239*I)*
   E^((0. + 1.4229429000000001*^-9*I)*t) + (0.0057300369 - 
       0.0071475265*I)*
   E^((0. + 6.629015100000001*^-9*I)*t) + (0.000072401667 - 
       0.000092434689*I)*E^((0. + 2.6555734*^-8*I)*t) == 0, t]
```

is crashing, apparently during a call to `GroebnerBasis`. I've let the developers know.